# Is there any way to send some data from my application e.g. quiz results

Tags: android, statistics

For example my application contains some quiz and I want to know the results from each user who installed the app. Is there any way to collect these stats?

Comment: `Is there any way to collect these stats?`.  Yes, there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Use for example the Parse Library. https://parse.com/docs/android_guide. It's very easy to set up.

When you have set it up and read their guide, you'll be able to save data very easily. I had mine up in about five, ten minutes and I can now save complex data.

The upside of using a cloud based solution (Parse is cloud based) is of course that you won't need your own backend (server and database). You won't have to code your backend script/servlet either.